# Can't connect to MariaDB using settings that worked for another project

Tags: django, mariadb

Someone please help me with a weird problem. I can't connect to my database through Django:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'ankush'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

The funny thing is I'm able to connect through command line using the same credentials and another Django app is using the same login. But this one refuses to play.

Here's my `pip list`:

```
 - amqp (1.4.9) 
 - anyjson (0.3.3) 
 - billiard (3.3.0.23) 
 - celery (3.1.23)
 - Django (1.9) 
 - django-celery (3.1.17) 
 - Faker (0.1.4) 
 - kombu (3.0.35)
 - mysqlclient (1.3.7) 
 - pip (8.1.2) 
 - pytz (2016.4) 
 - redis (2.10.5)
 - setuptools (21.2.1) 
 - wheel (0.29.0)
```

Also, for good measure, here's the `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'celery_demo',
        'USER ' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
    }   
}
```

Finally, I also have relevant privileges on the database:

```
MariaDB [celery_demo]> select user,host from mysql.db where db='celery_demo';
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
```

It does seem odd that while the username I'm passing is `root`, the error says `ankush@localhost`. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not specifying a username in your config:

```
'USER ' : 'root',
     ^----
```

`USER[space]` is NOT the same as `USER`

Comment: I am *so* embarrassed I can't even begin telling! Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. I've spent WAY too much of my life looking for complicated problems caused by "invisible" typos like that. Annoying as all hell... especially after you find it.